# Can I select a value from a table when the query restriction is from another table WITHOUT a join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

My model has 3 tables: **ACTORS**, **MOVIES** and **MOVIE_CAST**, which represents the relationship between ACTORS and MOVIES.

Table: ACTORS

- Columns: Name, Birth_Year
- Primary Key: Name, Birth_Year

Table: Movies

- Columns: Title, Release_Year, Genre, Director
- Primary Key: Title, Release_Year

Table: MOVIE_CAST

- Columns: Movie (FK), Movie_Release_Year (FK), Actor (FK), Birth_Yearh (FK)

---

**I need to list the actors and their birth year for all movies directed by ​'Wes Anderson'.**

I've tried 2 different queries: in the first I didn't join the tables and in the second I did it. Both gives me the same result but I'm not sure which one is right.

**First Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.NAME, A.BIRTH_YEAR
FROM ACTORS A, MOVIES M
WHERE M.DIRECTOR = 'Wes Anderson'
```

---

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.NAME, A.BIRTH_YEAR
FROM ACTORS A
    JOIN MOVIE_CAST MC ON MC.ACTOR = A.NAME AND MC.BIRTH_YEAR = A.BIRTH_YEAR
    JOIN MOVIES M ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND M.RELEASE_YEAR = MC.MOVIE_RELEASE_YEAR
WHERE M.DIRECTOR = 'Wes Anderson'
```

---

Which query is the correct one?

*P.S.: I'm using PostgreSQL/pgAdmin4 database by the way.*

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, both ways are legit... but I am a little surprised that the first query gave you what your expecting because there is no connection between table `ACTORS` and table `MOVIES` that's unless all the actors in the first table were directed by `Wes Anderson` (because the first table has no `director` column in it) so the `WHERE` isn't really working. The 2nd query looks a lot more detailed as you're making use of `JOIN`...

Comment: Comma means cross join but with lower precedence than keyword joins. (cross join where c) is (inner join on c). PS These are faqs. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; tags & versions; clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The second query is "right".

In the first query you have formed a "Cartesian product" (multiply each row in the actors table by the number of rows in the movies table) and that is why you need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` to reduce the number of rows returned. This is an inefficient method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.BIRTH_YEAR
FROM ACTORS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MOVIE_CAST MC JOIN
                   MOVIES M
                   ON M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE
              WHERE MC.ACTOR = A.NAME AND 
                    M.DIRECTOR = 'Wes Anderson'
             );
```

You can eliminate the inner join as well:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.BIRTH_YEAR
FROM ACTORS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MOVIE_CAST MC 
              WHERE MC.ACTOR = A.NAME AND
                    EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM MOVIES M
                            WHERE M.TITLE = MC.MOVIE AND
                                  M.DIRECTOR = 'Wes Anderson'
                           )
             );
```

When learning SQL, this version is often rendered using `IN` rather than `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.BIRTH_YEAR
FROM ACTORS A
WHERE A.NAME IN (SELECT MC.ACTOR
                 FROM MOVIE_CAST MC 
                 WHERE MC.MOVIE IN (SELECT M.TITLE
                                    FROM MOVIES M
                                    WHERE  M.DIRECTOR = 'Wes Anderson'
                                   )
                );
```

However, I recommend `EXISTS` over `IN` for two reasons.  First, it is often easier to optimize.  More importantly, I ALWAYS recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN` with subqueries due to the handling of `NULL` values.

I also think that you are much better off understanding how the `JOIN`s work.